# No difference in forward and redirect on Zimbra

Tags: email, smtp, zimbra

We have the case, that we need to forward all incoming emails to a other email address in the same domain.

Here is what is happening with **forward**:

1. test-a@example.com receives a email from outside@gmail.com
2. test-a@example.com **forwards** the email to end@example.com
3. The email should show from: test-a@example.com but still shows from: outside@gmail.com

Here is what is happening with **redirect**:

1. test-a@example.com receives a email from outside@gmail.com
2. test-a@example.com **redirects** the email to end@example.com
3. The email shows from: outside@gmail.com

So the redirect works as intended, but the forward does not.

Can anyone tell me why Zimbra is not functioning as I am expecting?

Comment: Did you found a solution for this meanwhile? I got the same issue, and mails getting blocked because Amazon SES rejects them.

Comment: Is there any smtp server established for outside@example.com?because as every time by default it's sending mail from this address.  Do one try send a sample mail to any other mailing address. and checkout the case